# Cakephp 2 beforeValidate with no data

Tags: cakephp, callback

I want to modify data in `beforeValidate()`, but I get only data from "default" column in my table, but no data from request;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first can modify data in controller's action function under $this->request->post request. Then your data will interact your model when you use model->set() or model->save(). Please share code to dig it more.

Answer (score -1):

When I use

```
$this -> {$this->modelClass} -> validates($this -> request -> data)
```

before

```
$this -> {$this->modelClass} -> save($this -> request -> data, false)
```

in beforeValidate there is no data. While I use only

`$this -> {$this->modelClass} -> save($this -> request -> data)`

in `beforeValidate` callback there is all I need :)

Thx

Comment: Use the edit functionality if you want to add further details, please do not misuse answers for that purpose.